# C: Wrong Characters with Second fgets

Tags: c, char, printf, fgets

I have this code:

```
char temp;
scanf("%c",&temp);
fgets(variable1,50,stdin);
strtok(variable1, "\n");

printf("%s ", variable1);
```

This gets a string with the possibility of having spaces and assigns it to the variable `variable1`. Later, I can print the string with no problem.

The problem comes when I add to code other `fgets`for gets other string in other variable.

```
if (1) {
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    fgets(variable2,50,stdin);
    strtok(variable2, "\n");

    printf("%s ", variable2);
}
```

The result complete is:

```
char temp;
scanf("%c",&temp);
fgets(variable1,50,stdin);
strtok(variable1, "\n");

printf("%s ", variable1);

if (1) {
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    fgets(variable2,50,stdin);
    strtok(variable2, "\n");

    printf("%s ", variable2);
}
```

`variable1` always works correctly. But I try print in some phrases with `%s` `variable2` but the result does not get the first character, only in second `scanf`. If I put HELLO, `variable2` is ELLO.

I have tested using another `temp` variable, another data, etc. But always get the same error.

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**
For more information. I use `scanf` because, if I do not use it, the program does not pause while waiting for the string. I use `strtok(variable1, "\n");` to remove the line break.

This program is inside a `while` and in `switch case`. I put the complete code:

```
case 4: printf( "Put equipo: "); 
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    fgets(equipo,50,stdin);
    strtok(equipo, "\n");

    if (Exists(equipo)) {
        printf("Put Piloto ");
        scanf("%c",&temp);
        fgets(piloto,50,stdin);
        strtok(piloto, "\n");
        printf("You said %s and %s", equipo, piloto);
    }

    break;
```

If I introduce like Equipo `HELLO` and like Piloto `FRIEND`, the output is:

`You said HELLO and RIEND`

Comment: What's the reason for `scanf("%c", &temp);`? If you're trying to skip over a newline, `fgets()` already reads that.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including all the variable declarations.

Comment: You print `variable1` after scanning `variable2`, so your `variable1` may not be as "correct" as you think.

Comment: The `if()` has `printf("%s ", variable1);`.  Is that the true code?   Is it really `printf("%s ", variable2);`?

Comment: what do you want to happen if they type more than 50 characters?

Comment: the UPDATE differs from the original question. You originally said the 2nd fgets gave garbage, but now you say it gives the right string missing the first character  (as is to be expected since you consumed that character with `scanf("%c"`). The updated code will work properly if you just remove the second `scanf("%c"` line (and don't type 50 characters in the first fgets).  Please review your question and make sure about what you are really asking. It would be good to include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have updated my answer based on your updated post, and information you provide in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-written based on OP latest edits to post, and comments...

You describe the need to simply obtain two strings from user input, remove the newlines from each, then package both into a message to `stdout`.  If this description actually matches what you need, change this code section:

```
...
scanf("%c",&temp);
fgets(equipo,50,stdin);
strtok(equipo, "\n");

if (Exists(equipo)) {
    printf("Put Piloto ");
    scanf("%c",&temp);
    fgets(piloto,50,stdin);
    strtok(piloto, "\n");
    printf("You said %s and %s", equipo, piloto);
...
```

To this:

```
...
printf("enter equipo: ");
if(fgets(equipo, sizeof(equipo), stdin))
{
    equipo[strcspn(equipo, "\n")] = 0; //remove newline 
    printf("enter piloto: ");
    if(fgets(piloto, sizeof(piloto), stdin))
    {
        piloto[strcspn(piloto, "\n")] = 0; 
        printf("You said %s and %s", equipo, piloto);
    }
}
...
```

Note:  `strtok(piloto, "\n");`  works, but has problems if user just hits `<return>`

By the way, [here are some other interesting ways to clear the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: @M.M - I think I see your point.  Bad choice of function and after OP updates to answer, would not have even addressed the main request.  Total re-write.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your example code. Could you update the question with your actual code?

I assume scanf should not be there?

This code works fine for me:

```
char var1[50], var2[50];
fgets(var1, 50, stdin);
strtok(var1, "\n");
printf("Var1: %s\n", var1);
if (1) {
        fgets(var2, 50, stdin);
        strtok(var2, "\n");
        printf("Var2 %s\n", var2);
}
```

Output:

```
Test1
Var1: Test1
Test2
Var2 Test2
```

Comment: If I do that, the program does not pause to wait for the string entered by the user, picks up a ` \ n`  directly as `var1`...

Comment: You should always get the return value of fgets